# Realtime Database Transaction does not seem to work when returning objects

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following transaction:

```
db.ref(`path/${id}`)
  .transaction((doc) => {
    console.log('calling once', doc);
    if (!doc) {
      console.log('initializing');
      return { subdoc: {} };
    }

    if (!doc.subdoc) {
      console.log('initializing subdoc (no inside?)');
      doc.subdoc = {};
    }

    console.log('doc:', doc);
    return doc;
  })
  .then(async (result) => {
    console.log('result', result);
    const val = await db.ref(`path/${id}`).get();
    console.log(val);
  });
```

where `db` is an instance of `firebase.database()`.

The intention of this transaction is to initialize the document with a subdoc if the correct structure doesn't exist yet.

However, the output I'm getting is the following:

```
calling once null
initializing
result {"committed": true, "snapshot": null}
null
```

The transaction update function **only gets called once** (unlike what's happening in a dozen other questions on StackOverflow), I'm never returning `null` to abort the transaction, and it's not an eventual consistency problem as when I check the console, the document remains unpopulated.

Further, if I replace the `{ subdoc: {} }` with just a string, the result gets properly set to the string. Even further, if a string is already populated and I try to replace it with an object, the string gets deleted! Why is it that any object gets treated as "set this value to null", and how can I populate it with an object?

If it's relevant, I'm testing this on the Realtime Database emulator rather than a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase's Realtime Database has essentially no concept of an "empty object", and this cascades upwards. For example,

```json
{
  "one": {
    "two": {
      "three": {}
    }
  }
}
```

is fundamentally equivalent to `null` (which is also equivalent to `undefined`, or just not having the key at all) because `"three"` gets set to `null`, which means `"two"` is equivalent to `{}` which also gets set to `null`, etc.

This can be illustrated by going into the Realtime database console and manually typing in the above structure and seeing that nothing happens when you try to add it. However, if you add something like `"bloop": "blop"` to `"three"`, the whole structure gets created.

While I feel this is under-documented, it's somewhat internally consistent, so I'm satisfied now that I know this.